# Suppose $\Lambda \in \mathcal A$ such that $\mu (\Lambda) >0$ and $f(x) <0$ for all $x \in \Lambda$. Prove that $\int_\Lambda f \, d \mu <0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space and $f:X \to \mathbb R$ be measurable. Suppose $\Lambda \in \mathcal A$ such that $\mu (\Lambda) >0$ and $f(x) <0$ for all $x \in \Lambda$.

It's trivial to prove $\int_\Lambda f \, d \mu \le 0$. I would like to ask how to prove $$\int_\Lambda f \, d \mu <0$$

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the integral of a non-negative measurable function is $0$ then the function is $0$ almost everywhere.

If $\int (-f)I_{\Lambda} d\mu=0$  then $-fI_{\Lambda} =0$ almost everywhere. Since $f <0$ on as set of positive measure this is a contradiction.

Alternatively, let $\Lambda_n=\Lambda \cap \{x: f (x) <-\frac  1n\}$. Note that $\int_{\Lambda} f d\mu \leq \int_{\Lambda_n} f d\mu\leq -\frac  1n \mu (\Lambda_n)<0$ if $n$ is sufficiently large since $\mu (\Lambda_n) \to \mu (\Lambda)$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

The following proof handles the special case where $\Lambda=X$ but can be easily generalized by applying it on $f1_{\Lambda}$.

Let $g=-f$ and for positive integer $n$ let $A_n=\{x\in X\mid g(x)\geq\frac1n\}$.

(Not essentially different, but I just prefer working with non-negative functions)

Then $A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq\cdots$ with $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n=\{g>0\}$.

Based on that it can be proved that: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n)=\mu(\{g>0\})$$

Then some $n$ must exist with $\mu(A_n)>0$.

Then based on $g\geq\frac1n1_{A_n}$ we find $$\int g\;d\mu\geq\int\frac1n1_{A_n}\;d\mu=\frac1n\mu(A_n)>0$$

Consequently: $$\int f\;d\mu=\int-g\;d\mu=-\int g\;d\mu<0$$